# Not finding players on Game Center. Am I testing my game wrong?

Tags: ios, game-center, gkmatchmaker

I have the game running on the Xcode simulator and also my iPhone. When I hit search they are both put into separate games, instead of one player joining the existing one. It is a turn based game, a player can take their first turn while Game Center is automatching. I am using two separate Game Center accounts with the Sandbox setting on. Any idea what I may be doing wrong? To those who have developed a Game Center supported game, how did you test it? Thanks for the help!

Some code:

```
- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers // view controller calls to find match - nothing if GC unavaiable
             viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {


if (!_enableGameCenter) return;


_matchStarted = NO; // Match not started yet
self.currentMatch = nil;
[viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init]; // Set number of players
request.minPlayers = minPlayers;
request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;

GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = // new instance of the GKMatchmakerViewController with the given request, sets its delegate to the GameKitHelper object, and uses the passed-in view controller to show it on the screen. Shows the user to search for a random player and start a game.
[[GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
mmvc.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self;

[viewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate

// A peer-to-peer match has been found, the game should start
- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match {
[viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
self.currentMatch = match;
GKTurnBasedParticipant *firstParticipant = [match.participants objectAtIndex:0];
if (firstParticipant.lastTurnDate == NULL) {
    // It's a new game!
    [delegate enterNewGame:match];
} else {
    if ([match.currentParticipant.player isEqual:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID]) {
        // It's your turn!
        [delegate takeTurn:match];
    } else {
        // It's not your turn, just display the game state.
        [delegate layoutMatch:match];
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code you are using to connect the players.

Answer (score 0):

Are you deleting old matches with a partially filled participant list generated during testing prior to starting/joining matches for a new test?  You can manually remove old matches from the game center app or use `loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler` which "loads the turn-based matches involving the local player and creates a match object for each match" at the appropriate time in your code to identify matches for deletion.  Refer to Apple's documentation to identify the steps to properly leave, end, and remove a match.